# Does finally { _someLock.EnterWriteLock(); } make any sense?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

I see in code of one big project such pattern:

```
try {} finally { _someLock.EnterWriteLock(); }

try
{
...
}
finally
{
   _someLock.ExitWriteLock();
}
```

Does it make in any sense to enter lock in finally?

===================

Update:
I found the source of such pattern.

http://chabster.blogspot.com/2013/07/a-story-of-orphaned-readerwriterlockslim.html . What can you say?

Comment: With an empty `try` block? IMO...no, no sense (and probably it'll be optimized away by compiler). If `try` block isn't empty then it may be part of some mad logic-program flow (!).

Comment: @Adriano first try is emty, second contans logics of file deletion and so on

Comment: The first one does not make sense, but you already knew this, right?

Comment: Then IMO it is useless. AFAIK a `finally` block won't enable any special compiler/JIT/CLR behavior.

Comment: @flup yes, but i was surprised... i thought - maybe i don't know something...

Comment: @Adriano Empty try blocks are not optimized away I suppose

Comment: @Adriano please see an update

Comment: The code in your question does not copy the code from the article you've linked. If you copy the code from the article, it makes more sense, and the justification in the article seems genuine enough. (That said, I don't have time to examine the .NET source code to confirm the article's assertion...)

Comment: ok.closed. removed link

Comment: I recommend you to add those links back(Rollback your edit). because for future readers it will be hard to understand the comments about what we're talking about. It gives more context too:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't. Empty **try**/finally block defends from excecuting finally even when the thread is aborted when it reaches `try` block.

In fact it is **harmful** in your case.

Consider if thread abort exception is thrown when executing `try`

```
try
{
    //Thread is here and abort requested
}
finally { _someLock.EnterWriteLock(); }//Aborted thread takes the lock!

try
{
...
}
finally
{
   _someLock.ExitWriteLock();//Never gonna execute since thread is aborted. You're screwed.
}
```

Comment: @BransDs: as per my other comment, the code in the article you linked *isn't* the same as the code you posted. What you've posted has the risk outlined by Sriram here; the code in the article does not.

Comment: @DanPuzey this article explain why is this can be useful. The link sends my the autor of code in this question

Comment: @BransDs I agree with Dan, Both code are not same. pls note there is **nested** try. here it is different.

Comment: It makes sense if there are **multiple instructions inside `finally` block**. `EnterWriteLock()` is _protected_ itself against this situation so in this case it's useless (useless = not harmful and not good because **it behaves exactly in the same way, with or without** `finally` block).

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. Maybe if you want to obfuscate your code